# Does Intellij idea support groovy beans configuration?

Tags: intellij-idea, spring-4

Spring 4 supports bean configuration [using Groovy](https://spring.io/blog/2014/03/03/groovy-bean-configuration-in-spring-framework-4). 
You can define your beans using `beans` closure and it looks cleaner than xml. Moreover you can add flexible logic because it is a Groovy script.

My question is:

Is it possible to make IntelliJ IDEA understand such bean declarations? The problem is that when I use `@Autowired`, IDE says:

```
Could not autowire
```

Because it does not understand Groovy beans.

And by the way is it a good approach to use Groovy configuration for Spring? I did not notice people use it much in their projects even though i found them more convenient than XML.

Answer (score 0):

I use Groovy beans with IntelliJ. It seems to work perfectly. I'm not sure what I've done configuration wise with Idea, but I do not get the error you are seeing.

We mix Groovy/Java DSL with some XML across our projects. We switched to the Groovy/Java DSL to get away from XML configurations. We started with all XML and are migrating to Groovy/Java DSL.

The only issue we've seen with Groovy is the lack of typing sometimes makes writing unit tests laborious.

IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.3
Build #IU-145.1617, built on June 3, 2016
JRE: 1.8.0_76-release-b198 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o

Comment: Can you please upload a simple project for me with .ipr and .idea files?

Comment: Sorry, we are not using the Groovy Beans syntax to configure beans. We use groovy, but with the @Bean annotation.
 @Bean(name = "watch-file")
 RouteBuilder watchFile(@Value("${watched}") final String directory) {
  return new RouteBuilder() {
   @Override
   public void configure() throws Exception {
    logger.debug("watching {}", directory);
    from(String.format("file:%s?delete=true", directory)).to("activemq:queue:sync");
   }
  };
```